# Delete specific lines using sed in multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, file, text, sed

I was wondering how to delete the first 196 lines of multiple html documents with sed.
The directory structure I have goes as follows:

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: If you're trying to delete a known range of lines (e.g. lines 1 to 196, as in your question), I'm not sure that `sed` is the right tool.

Comment: what tool would you suggest? im also using sed to replace some lines with other strings

Comment: `tail` would be the right tool to select the lines at the tail of a file. sed cannot work on strings, only REs, if you need to replace strings then you need to use awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find /rootdir/ -name index.html -exec sed -i '1,196d' {} \;
```

Comment: it didnt run in all the folders, would it look like this?

Comment: @user3550278 it would run on all index.html files recursively in `/rootdir/`, e.g. `/rootdir/foo/bar/index.html`

Comment: @user3550278 For doing this on multiple `html` files all you need to do is modify `-name index.html` to `-name "*.html"`

Comment: when i run it it does this http://i.imgur.com/9xjnibQ.png

Comment: Is your web root directory called `/rootdir`? if not, use the appropriate directory name

Comment: @user3550278 That means the command is still running. You are updating several thousand files, that has ought to take some time. If you want to debug the command, run it against a scaled down version of your file structure that contain few sub-directories and files. And as Mark stated in his comment, also ensure you are running it against your master directory by verifying the name.